# Ban a specific site from showing up in Firefox Top sites, in a New Tab

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-20.04

Using FF 75 under Ubuntu 20.04.

**Can I ban a specific site from ever showing in the Top Sites, whenever I open a New Tab?**

Comment: If you are trying to hide certain adult sites, consider in-private browsing before you start, and every trace of such session will be gone after you close the in-private browser.

Comment: @LPChip - No, it is not an adult site. But it is a site that may be visited often during some periods of time, but I still don't want it to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is apparently possible](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1244964#answer-1184233).
In the New Tab, point to the top right corner of the icon that one means to ban from the New Tab page. Three dots will show up. Click to *Open menu* -> *Dismiss*.
This adds the URL to be banned to a `browser.newtabpage.blocked` preference in the `about:config` page.